# How can I preserve sequential white-space characters in HTML?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

More than one consecutive white spaces given inside an HTML code is treated as one (just one white-space). Is there any CSS style to make these consecutive White-spaces apply in the page?

Any help is appreciated.

```
<p class="anyClass"> I want white-space           here.</p>
```

Comment: Instead of asking about your proposed solution, describe the actual problem. Chances are there's a better way.

Comment: from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space , what have you tried that did not work for you ?

Comment: `&nbsp;` non-breaking space

Answer (score -1):

`&nbsp;` can do the work

`&emsp;` for 2 spaces